# table.remove in lua acting weirdly

Tags: lua, lua-table

```
tbl1 = {1}

tbl2 = tbl1

table.remove(tbl2,1)

print(tbl1[1])
-- >> nill
```

The above example is a simplification of the problem in my code, by removing a index from tbl2, it also removes from tbl1, is there a reason for this to be happening?

Comment: The assignment `tbl2 = tbl1` copies a pointer to the object, not the object itself.

Comment: that would solve the issue, was not aware of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables in Lua are *references* to objects, and so `a=b` sets the variable named `a` to refer to the object that `b` refers to. If `b` is a table, then after the assignment both `a` and `b` point to the same table object.

Comment: "[Tables, functions, threads, and (full) userdata values are objects: variables do not actually contain these values, only references to them. Assignment, parameter passing, and function returns always manipulate references to such values; these operations do not imply any kind of copy.](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#2.1)"